# Fixing invalid connectivity in a geometric network dataset in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geometric-network

I've looked hard for answers to this and whilst there is a fair bit on geometric network datasets in ArcGIS, I'm yet to have found an answer to this question, so fingers crossed this is not a double post.

I'm researching river networks and need to construct simple, directed graphs that eventually will be generated by classifying rasters, conversion to shapefiles/feature classes and then collapsing rasters to channel centrelines (points and polylines).  The network effectively consists of channels (edges) connecting bifurcations and confluences (nodes).

I have built a geometric network from point and polyline feature classes and set connectivity rules for edges to connect to nodes/junctions and when I use the verify connectivity tool in the Geometric Network Editing toolbar it says "all network connectivity is correct".  However, when I use the validate feature tool in the standard Editor toolbar, I get a message that says "edge features cannot connect to edge features via junction features" (see below).  Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

[image: Validate features connectivity problem]

Comment: Please only ask one question per question.  Either refine down to the one question you want to ask, or ask a separate question for each.  Recommend you take the [tour]

Comment: You refer to an Esri White Paper - can you please include a link to that white paper?

Comment: Are the lines that your selected feature connects broken/split at the point of connection?  Is your geometric network set up using Simple or Complex edges?

Comment: Thanks for the input Midavalo and noted, only one question per question in future.

Comment: This is the ESRI white paper: http://downloads.esri.com/support/whitepapers/other_/arcgis_schematics-connectivity_1206.pdf

Comment: The network is built with simple edges.  Not sure what you mean by "broken/split at the point of connection".  The network is comprised of point features and connected by line features.  There is one line element (edge) connecting each pair of nodes. Hope that helps. Thanks.

Comment: if you [edit] your question to refine it down to one question it could possibly be re-opened and then answerable.

Comment: By  "broken/split at the point of connection" I mean does the line your selection connects to actually end at the same point as your selected line, or does it continue on to another point?

Comment: the error message in your image suggests there are geometric-network rules in place that your existing lines don't adhere to.  What rules have you applied on your network?

Comment: The lines end at the ends of any single selected line.  Each line is a single element (polyline feature class) that should that is snapped to the nodes (point feature class).  When I generate the geometric network the nodes become the network junctions.

Comment: In terms of rules, the connection rules set in the connectivity tab of the geometric networks properties window are that network links can connect to nodes and junctions, and nodes and junctions respectively can connect to links.  There are no junction sub-types, thus no possibility of applying rules to junction sub-types.

Comment: I've also edited the question to contain a single question, so if it could be reopened then that would be great!  Thanks.